# IdentityReference to Distinguishedname (Dn)?

Tags: powershell

If I have something like DOMAIN\Domain Admins (IdentityReference from Get-ACL), how can I get its distinguishedname (DN)?

Answer (score 1):

Search AD:

```
$searcher = [ADSISEARCHER]'(cn=domain admins)'
$searcher.FindOne().Properties.distinguishedname
```

Comment: This is weird.  So Domain Admin works, but we have groups like called [Dept] Group X that has an alias (?) groupx.  If I search on [Domain]/groupx, which I change to cn=groupx, it does not pull back a properties of distinguished name or name.  How do you address this?

Comment: I'm not following you, groups have brackets in the name?

Comment: Yes, although they are starting to remove those.  You know how if you use the Active Directory Users and Computers it shows the group icon and the name.  That name has [Dept] Group X.  If you look the the Group Name (pre-Windows 2000), it shows the groupx in the textbox.  For some reason if I take change cn=groupx to cn=[Dept] Groupx, it pulls back the distinguished name.  I want to be able to use the groupx name if you have info on how to do that with the adsisearcher.

Comment: I figured it out.  The groupx name is the samaccountname.  I changed the search to be: $searcher = [ADSISEARCHER]"(&(objectCategory=group)(samaccountname=$cn))".  The next obvious question would be how to do an -or with this--in that, I want to check if it finds samaccountname or name to equal cn=groupx in case groupx is not samaccountname.

Comment: You can start here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996205(v=exchg.65).aspx